# Text inside h3 tag not visible in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have text in the h3 tag, it is working fine in FF and chrome . But in IE8 the text is not visible. Aint knowing what is wrong .here is the html.

html:

```
<div id="right">
  <h3>
    profile
    <div id='upload' class="save" style="float:right; display:none; font-family: comicsans; padding-right: 20px; cursor:pointer">
      <img src="jqe13/image/fb.PNG">
      <span class="blink">**Save**</span>
    </div>
  </h3>
</div>
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Is it because you have `display:none;`?

Comment: but the image in the div is still visible..

Comment: `div` is not allowed within `h3`. Fix your invalid HTML.

Comment: image in the div is visible..

Comment: There must be something you are not telling / showing us because the image can't be visible with this code.

Comment: IE is a stupid browser hehe. Try adding `display:none !important;` or in stylesheet `#upload > img { display:none !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div id="right">
      <h3>
        profile
      </h3>
<div id='upload' class="save" style="float:right; display:none; font-family: comicsans; padding-right: 20px; cursor:pointer">
          <img src="jqe13/image/fb.PNG">
          <span class="blink">**Save**</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first thing is that div should not be used under h3 tag so it might be creating problem and another thing is that for the div you have set the css property to dislay:none it will not let you display any content inside it. so if want to display the content under the div you will have to remove this porperty.

Hope this will work for you.